# How to specify pid file in relative path in rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pid

I specify the location of pid file in `rails s` command by appending `--pid` option.

`rails s -d --pid ~/foo.pid`

To stop the server, I use the following code.

`kill -9 $(cat ~/foo.pid)`

The problem is, the pid file created by the first command is found at `/foo.pid`, not `~/foo.pid`.

How can I specify the pid file path in relative path in `rails s` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a standard shell (bash)

```
$ rails s -d --pid `pwd`/foo.pid
```

The backticks execute the pwd (print working directory) command and substitutes the output in that spot.

Comment: not working in ubuntu 14.04.1 & LTS Rails 4.1.8 (--pid option)

Comment: @SergioBelevskij that's because older versions of rails used a different parser and so you had to use the syntax `--pid=/path/to/pid` (note the equals sign)